# jQuery / javascript stress performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery exhaustively to process large xml files (which act as data-model/metadata and as real model data for my HTML5 view).  Now the question is - I was wondering how large or how big file sizes could it handle? I am already handling size of 1 mb xml files - what happens if I try to process 15mb files? Would it be able to handle such a large data at all? If not what is the way to go - Client side caching? How does jQuery support it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this? Why not a server side language?

Comment: As far as jQuery goes, jQuery doesn't really have anything to do with the parsing of the XML other than providing a shortcut to the browser's xml parser, you're limited by what the browser can handle with the client machine's capabilities and the given browser. For example, IE9/10 on a newish (5 years old or newer) machine would be able to handle much more than an older machine running IE<9.

Comment: Basically this is just another view (on HTML5) on top of what we already have (in silverlight) - Silverlight handles it pretty well and thus we didnt want to add more classes in server just for HTML view.

Comment: Hi Kevin, before we decided to use jQuery for xml processing we did some research and even consulted jQuery experts - from all the documentations and apis that they do provide and even from many discussions been done in Stack Overflow - we saw that jQuery could be used to process XML without reservations.  As a matter of fact, it has been working pretty well.  Our only concern is now performance...

Comment: Right, but all jQuery does is pass the string passed to `$.parseXML()` (or returned from an ajax request with dataType xml) to the browser's native parsing method. For example, most browsers use `window.DOMParser`

Comment: Yes. But with added support of .find .children and other similar apis it makes the job much easier.

Comment: Most of the time jQuery is still just delegating to the browser's built-in APIs. If you're so concerned about performance with a 15mb file, why don't you just test this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no limited on jQuery/javaScript. It depends on the browsers and your computer here is the summary of all the limitations by browsers/technology.

[image]

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side so its limitations come from the browser and the operating system. Firefox also has some extra cleverness to halt a long running script and let the user decide if they want it to keep executing, so even if you intend to utilize a lot of ram and CPU, the user might click "stop script" and prevent your script from completing.

Answer (score 0):

Time required to process and ability to process successfully a given amount of data without crashing the browser depends on the client machine/device and the browser.

So the answer has no direct response.

Make tests...